# How to connect to MinIo server using temporary credentials and ASW S3 client in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, minio, aws-sdk-net, aws-sts

I am able to connect to MinIo bucket and upload objects using AWS SDK and S3 client by passing MinIo credentials in C#.

````
           {
               AuthenticationRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1.SystemName,
               ServiceURL = minioURL,
               ForcePathStyle = true // MUST be true to work correctly with MinIO server
           };

           var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(minioAccessKey, minioSecretKey, s3Config);```



This works fine. Now I am trying to connect to MinIo using assumerole  temporary credentials and I couldn't do it in C#. Can someone help me to generate temporary assumerole credentials or point me in the right direction?
````